# FireBase Unity- Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord$Op;

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have a game in Unity that I am compiling for Android. 
I encountered a few building issues previously but these were resolved with the addition of the build.gradle file. 
However, all of a sudden I am yet again unable to build the project and I am encountering the following error: Multiple dex files define

```
 CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord$Op;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
]
stdout[
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Matth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Matth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:extractProguardFiles
:preReleaseBuild
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBaseLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasementLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasksLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImplLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsUnity443Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppUnity443Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthUnity443Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommonLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIidLicense1180Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidSdk470Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidWrapperReleaseLibrary
:prepareUnityAdsLibrary
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl
:Firebase:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:compileLint
:Firebase:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:processReleaseResources
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:bundleRelease
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:javaPreCompileDebug
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
69 actionable tasks: 59 executed, 10 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I have the following Build.Gradle file in the top level of my project (outside the Assets folder and alongside the c# project and solutions)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

My module Build.Gradle located (Assets/Plugin/Android) contains the following

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.9"
    }
    buildTypes {
       ///
    }   
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")) {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"        
    exclude group: "com.google.firebase" 
} 
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EDIT. 
I have unchecked Development build in Unity and I get a different error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setChannelId(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced method 'void createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced method 'android.app.NotificationChannel getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhd: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp()' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhe: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp(java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 11s
]
stdout[
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Matth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Matth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:extractProguardFiles
:preReleaseBuild
:checkReleaseManifest
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBaseLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasementLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1180Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasksLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImplLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsUnity443Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppUnity443Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthUnity443Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommonLicense1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1180Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIidLicense1180Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidSdk470Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidWrapperReleaseLibrary
:prepareUnityAdsLibrary
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl
:Firebase:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:compileLint
:Firebase:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:processReleaseResources
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:bundleRelease
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
ProGuard, version 5.3.2
Reading input...
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\libs\android-support-v4.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\libs\bolts-android-1.2.0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\libs\com.android.support.support-annotations-25.2.0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\libs\unity-classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\ebe8ba175f79c888e2c720bb1eee4238141b22df\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\1bfd9bf8f2f5e3bfd1536eb5010c3501d19a8ab3\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\5d9a078ae1bbc29d8534b94e7cf3c2a135da9f4e\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\59609a6cffd07716bb9d17d37c8502ede98e3efb\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\aa22ee90f144915c6244b0cafefc3c1f7a465e4e\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\84b45a492153574abd446d52ccba8b2e02583534\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\08cb788b258ad9f5fddd741137865bdf9c9bbbc6\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\c9cdd0db0496a5a3ead166b2debf0d43925e76b6\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\537f6802d4764651fe083b707b5f5cddcc9dcd31\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\a2a61b0f14365a2cd4faca8c817e426dfb925d58\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\a6bd74aa3d99fd3f833cfd706227b39917c0bba1\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\2da564a1f8127c4a8453b14804a69452651863ef\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\f8dea0763daf2e3e9e069a5327b9e01e67a9285b\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\5a1c2132fc91aae94bb0e48689a444a44ec2a5e0\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\67c4f37350ec96f79f2edce6441fb90a604576bc\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\b7a6038dabeba52fe4286eec0bd777b4e2be3422\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\e3ad79add4c95fdc9c9154f28035401eb3e48b5f\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\0e3bc8c01c4e2d93609f311195d7d5a6c5305d98\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\f4366b4c4a4ed37d396e0fd2dfd6fb1e72c78911\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\b305aa5dedbc41ad7b0d4db3d368aab9b2b5997c\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\b2cec4d192f2d8807702e8c09161ef0caa3fa358\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\78e6809f633c79a060e1124bc29ffbe3a97ea559\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\1e0a4f4ee9c21baab7f317771a1e6c168f0dd3a7\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\b2f2e7a6a6c00e51077329353ba39d881c3e3c3a\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\13b1c589aea07700d64fba1e600045db543ea324\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\b93d3de98a9cfffc7509ee3d62af12fd855d0858\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\31fd0f8c2cc93f4f16765b4e2a86617e0adc3b47\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\a79a02af7468bcedeae48c542cf52be436c79362\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\.android\build-cache\fa50942623bc31b7f1867ab44f4c8a803ad78837\output\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\Firebase\build\intermediates\bundles\default\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\release\jars\2\1f\main.jar] (filtered)
Reading program directory [C:\Users\Matth\Desktop\Endless Jumper\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\classes\release] (filtered)
Reading library jar [C:\Users\Matth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\Matth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.HttpResponseCache]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.ReleasableResultGuardian'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.crash.internal.api.CrashApiImpl'
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgn: can't find dynamically referenced class android.os.SystemProperties
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcjn: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzffl: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzffm: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.Extension
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzffp: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionSchemaFull
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfgq: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.DescriptorMessageInfoFactory
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfhb: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldSchemaFull
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfhx: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfhx: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSetSchema
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfiq: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.io.Memory
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfiq: can't find dynamically referenced class org.robolectric.Robolectric
Note: com.facebook.unity.UnityReflection accesses a field 'currentActivity' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer { android.app.Activity currentActivity; }'
Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'MODULE_ID' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { java.lang.String MODULE_ID; }'
Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'MODULE_VERSION' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { int MODULE_VERSION; }'
Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'sClassLoader' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader { java.lang.ClassLoader sClassLoader; }'
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvl accesses a field 'SDK_INT' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.os.Build$VERSION { int SDK_INT; }'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown field 'com.go<message truncated>
```

I have rolled the Unity collab project back to when I did the last successful build but I had the same issue error. 
My build settings are as follows:

[image]

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Comment: you have duplicated support library dependencies. Please attach your  module build.gradle.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I have added this info now. See edited question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833504/1238647

Answer (score 0):

From the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
```

You see that you have different version of Firebase and Google Play Services. You need to make both using the same version. So, it should be like this:

```
// change to the version you need.
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
```

And you also need to check if `react-native-google-signin` to make sure it is using the same version too. Don't use `+` for version. The easiest way is excluding both Firebase and Google Play service from it:

```
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")) {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"        
    exclude group: "com.google.firebase" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just tried this and unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

I've updated the question with the error and updated the gradle. This is my first real experience with Gradle so there could be something obvious that I've missed.

Comment: @user1662292: what library is used inside `:react-native-google-signin`? Is there any support library? And check your libs directory in case you're also using jar file.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks again for the response. 
I can't find any file or anywhere in my project that refers to React-native-google-signin. Where would I expect to find this information?

If this helps, Out of my listed dependencies the only one in my Plugin/android folder is com.google.firebase:firebase-core-11.8.0. The other two dependencies are not there.

In my Assets/Plugins/Android/libs folder I have Android-Support-v4.jar, bolts-android-1.2.0.jar and a couple of facebook-andriod-sdk aar files.

Comment: Try changing `9.2.1` to `11.8.0` because you're using `com.google.firebase:firebase-core-11.8.0`

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but no luck. 
I have updated the question with more information. When I uncheck Development build I get a different error - I hope this new information may be useful